# performance of system clock in c and c++11

Tags: c++, c, performance, c++11, time

I have noticed that C-style to compute the elapsed time is faster than if I do it using C++11. The difference is getting smaller if the execution needs more time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

long fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n < 3) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    /* C++11-Style */
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;

    /* C-Style */
    clock_t c_start, c_end;
    double c_elapsed;

    /* Start */
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    c_start = clock();

    std::cout << "f(30) = " << fibonacci(30) << '\n';

    /* End */
    c_end = clock();
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    /* Compute Elasped time */
    c_elapsed = ((double)(c_end-c_start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
              << "  elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << "c_elapsed time: " << c_elapsed << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

The result is

```
f(30) = 832040
finished computation at Fri Jul  4 05:03:10 2014
  elapsed time: 0.00417783s (C++11)
c_elapsed time: 0.003686s   (C)
```

Why this is the case?

Comment: Your `chrono` point takes into considering the second `clock` call too.

Comment: You should use a heavier workload to avoid inaccuracies and overhead, check if the ratio stays this way when you scale the Fibonacci argumanet

Comment: When you start your `chrono` based clock, you are including the cost of the call to the `c-style` clock. You start the c-style clock later and stop it sooner. You should split your function into 2 functions, each of which uses only ONE of the methodologies and does the exact same workload otherwise.

Comment: When I run this I get almost no difference except the second call (whichever one it is) is slightly later than the first.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Should I have a degree in computer science to ask questions?

Comment: @CroCo: I downvoted you because, frankly, this is a thousand miles from "Have a degree in CS". This is more than a bit basic. The problem you have has nothing to do with the fact that C++11 appears to be slower and everything to do with the fact that you don't have the first clue about how to construct a remotely fair benchmark. This is not a problem that we could possibly remedy in an SO answer, so your question is quite unfit for this site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Puppy; your points have been taken in my consideration. My background is electronics. I just wanna enhance my programming skills by doing codes and reading. I have no place to ask except here, so bear with me. Cheers

Comment: @CroCo: _"I have no place to ask except here, so bear with me."_ Sorry but that logic does not make sense. The internet is a vast place, and is not even the only (nay, not even the best!) place to learn this stuff. Certainly that is no reason in itself to post here. The site's goal is not optional, specified only for those for whom it is easy to follow. _"Bear with me"_ suggests that you assert we ought to put aside everything this place stands for just because _you_ have a problem, but that is not true at all. That all being said, I think you're doing okay here overall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is hardly fair! This is for several reasons.

#### Broken benchmarking

You have `clock()` calls surrounding only the fibonacci calculation, but `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` calls surrounding the fibonacci calculation *plus two `clock()` calls*!

Let's look at that again:

```
  C                | C++11
  ====================================
  fibonacci(30)    | clock()
                   | fibonacci(30)
                   | clock()
```

It seems wholly reasonable that your C++11 version should result in a higher duration.

Re-run your benchmark with isolated mechanisms (such as an entirely separate file for each variant of code), and also increase the size of the calculation being timed to get more meaningful results; run it 100 times and take an average, or something.

#### Different semantics

That being said, I *am* seeing fairly consistently that [`clock()` is slower](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a38d64071a29ed):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
#ifdef CSTYLE
        clock();
#else
        std::chrono::system_clock::now();
#endif
}
```

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && time ./a.out &&
> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -DCSTYLE main.cpp && time ./a.out
> real  0m0.027s
> user  0m0.008s
> sys   0m0.016s
>
> real  0m0.038s
> user  0m0.000s
> sys   0m0.036s
> ```

I don't know why this is but, consequently, comparing `elapsed_seconds.count()` and `c_elapsed` and expecting to make any firm rationalisations about the result is largely folly.

Comment: I feel like there's no way this could have gone 2 years without being noticed, but doesn't your data above show that system_clock::now() is *faster*?  The version that uses clock() takes .038 seconds and the other version takes .027 seconds.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

There are several things wrong with this test.

1. It's one sample.

   Who knows what will happen next time one runs it. For all we know the difference could fluctuate between 0.002 and -42.1723 and this sample happens to show a difference close to 0.002. How can one know if the results are reproducible, or how the results vary if one only tries it once?
2. It's one sample taken with clocks of completely unknown characteristics.

   What if the first clock can only measure in increments of 0.00417783s and the second one can only measure in increments of 0.003686s but the experiment actually ran in 0.005s? How can one know if the difference in results is meaningful if one has no idea how well the clocks can measure?
3. It measures a different thing for each clock.

   The first clock measurement includes two calls to the second clock's code. How can one know if the difference in results is explained by a difference in the clocks if the clocks are not the only thing that changed from one measurement to the other?

The test is therefore meaningless.

A better test should:

1. Ascertain the characteristics of the clocks.

   First and foremost one needs to know how precise the clocks can measure time. Knowing that, one can scale the experiment so that the effect of low precision can be reduced to the point we don't care about it.
2. Measure the same thing with both clocks.

   Compare apples to apples. There should be no difference in the two measurements other than the part one is interested in: the clocks.
3. Take more than one sample.

   By sampling more than once one gets to know if the result was a single fluke (possibly caused by external factors) and how the results can vary.